# How to get execution time in rails console?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, time, console

I want compare time of execution `Post.all` and `SELECT * FROM posts` (or some other statements) How can i get execution time of `Post.all` ?

Answer (score 271, accepted):

```
timing = Benchmark.measure { Post.all }
```

The various attributes of the object returned (Benchmark::Tms) are provided [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark/Tms.html).

Comment: I've found this post very useful: http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2013/07/22/benchmarking-your-ruby-code/

Comment: @Bohdan Would it be better to add another answer or comment with reference to the benchmark-ips gem? You've done quite a big edit to the answer there which changes it significantly and rather reduces the appropriateness of the votes on it already.

Comment: @Bohdan Upvoted. You can always change the accepted answer too if the new answer has become more appropriate.

Comment: This works. I wanted to know the unit of time is seconds as well, found it https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html.

Answer (score 5):

With [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) gem:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'benchmark/ips'
=> true 
2.3.0 :002 > Benchmark.ips do |x|
2.3.0 :003 >       x.report("add: ") { 1+2 }
2.3.0 :004?>       x.report("div: ") { 1/2 }
2.3.0 :005?>       x.report("iis: ") { 1/2.0 }
2.3.0 :006?>   end
Warming up --------------------------------------
           add:    280.299k i/100ms
           div:    278.189k i/100ms
           iis:    266.526k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
           add:      11.381M (± 4.5%) i/s -     56.901M in   5.010669s
           div:       9.879M (± 4.6%) i/s -     49.518M in   5.024084s
           iis:       9.289M (± 4.2%) i/s -     46.376M in   5.001639s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of how to measure performance automatically in rails console using gem: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/execution_time

It's showing similar information which you already see during requests.

Sample:

`[METRICS]  Completed in 908.3ms | Allocations: 2894 | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms (queries: 13)`